# Call a method every time I leave a page on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I would like to call a method every time I leave a page on Laravel. How do I do this? Is there a way to do it the way middleware does when we get to a page?

Comment: in a middleware you can check the previous request and if its not null you can execute your code

Comment: "leave" a page, not sure what that actually means in this context

Comment: I meant before close a page. Not start a new one

Comment: make an ajax call that capture when user ieave page with `onbeforeunload` event. Create a controller with a middleware that you make.

Comment: A post or get ajax call ?